# In Swift, how to generically limit function to types that understand T + T

Tags: generics, swift

I would like to have a generic function that can use the plus operator on two values.

```
class funccalc {
    func doAdd<T>(x:T,y:T) -> T {
        return x + y
    }
}
let a = funccalc()
println(a.doAdd(1, y: 4))
println(a.doAdd(23.54, y:200))
```

I get an error on `return x + y`

Is my only option to follow the suggestion in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24047239/67566, and create my own protocol as `Int` and `String` would define the operator?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using the protocol `AdditiveArithmetic`?

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/additivearithmetic

Looks like thats exactly what you are looking for. That protocol has the method:

`static func + (Self, Self) -> Self`

Using that protocol your method becomes:

```
class funccalc {
    func doAdd<T: AdditiveArithmetic>(x:T,y:T) -> T {
        return x + y
    }
}
```

Comment: Btw, this method returns given number unchanged

Comment: @Robert Dresler, thanks for pointing that out, just updated the method.

Answer (score 13):

You may have a similar need for other functions too and implementing them for all integer and floating point types (or other "summable" things) would cause massive code duplication.

One partial solution, specifically for +, -, *, /, % is to require conformance to IntegerArithmeticType protocol:

```
func example<T: IntegerArithmeticType>(x: T, y: T) -> T { return x + y }
println(example(40, 2)) // --> 42
```

This does not apply to floating point types because they do not implement overflow operations defined in _IntegerArithmeticType protocol, which IntegerArithmeticType inherits from.

However, extending types for a specific globally defined operator function conformance is not as "annoying" as you might think:

```
protocol Summable { func +(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self }

extension Int: Summable {}
extension Double: Summable {}
extension String: Summable {}
// extension for any other types... you are in full control!
```

You do this once, then forevermore you can use Summable in you code:

```
func example<T: Summable>(x: T, y: T) -> T { return x + y }

println( example("4", "2") ) // --> 42
```

Indeed, and as @connor pointed out, this is equivalent to @Jean-PhilippePellet's answer you mentioned.

Answer (score 6):

You should do as that answer suggested. Create a protocol for your use and extend all of the classes that you want to use it. Then make sure T implements that protocol in your method signature.

You can't use an "addable" protocol because there isn't one in swift. The swift library actually creates a function + for each valid addition operations. Command-click on something like Int to see where all of these are defined. It will look something like this:

```
//....
func +(lhs: Int8, rhs: Int8) -> Int8
func +(lhs: UInt16, rhs: UInt16) -> UInt16
func +(lhs: Int16, rhs: Int16) -> Int16
func +(lhs: UInt32, rhs: UInt32) -> UInt32
func +(lhs: Int32, rhs: Int32) -> Int32
//etc...
```

Comment: I was hoping there would be another way, as making a new protocol just to get this type of functionality seems a bit annoying.  The command-clck operation is new to me, I will need to try that.