# How to write a function to do the dot product on n-dimensional vector?

Tags: swift, operator-overloading

First of all, here's a short reminder on what the [dot product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Geometric_definition) is.

I would like to be able to have a chunk of code, which I can use in the following manner:

```
 let x = Vector<Double>(dimensions: 3)
 let y = Vector<Double>(dimensions: 3)

 //...
 //assign some values (coordinates) to x and y
 //x.dotProduct(y)
```

How do I implement `dotProduct` as a *class* method?

Here's what doesn't work:

```
func dot(vector: Point<T>) -> Double {
    var sum: Double = 0.0
    for index in 0...vector.size {
       sum += sum + vector[index] * point[index]
    }
}
```

Error message is:

```
error: cannot invoke '*' with an argument list of type '(@lvalue T, $T14)'
```

New `func dot`:

```
 func dot(vector: Point<T>) -> T {
    var sum = 0 as T
    println(point.count)

    for index in 0..<point.count{
        println(vector[index])
        println(point[index])

        sum += vector[index] * point[index]
    }

    return sum
}
```

Comment: define "doesn't work".

Comment: As I tried to explain in the answer to your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28302650/how-to-create-a-generic-class-in-swift-that-accepts-doubles-and-ints, you have to  define a protocol with the required operations "addition" and "multiplication".  Here is a similar question about defining a generic dot-product: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25592838/generics-of-raw-types-int-float-double-create-weird-error-messages (where the code is based on this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24047239/1187415).

Comment: @MartinR I simply cannot get those to work.

Comment: Is Point the class from your previous question? And how is Vector defined?

Comment: x.dotProduct(y) is the badness without good. x •= y is the way to go. https://github.com/mattt/Euler/blob/master/Euler.swift

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update 4:

This works:

```
class Vector<T: SummableMultipliable> {
    var dimensions: Int
    var coordinates: [T]

    init(dimensions: Int) {
        self.dimensions = dimensions
        self.coordinates = [T](count: dimensions, repeatedValue: 0 as T)
    }

    func dotProduct<T>(vector: Vector<T>) -> T {
        assert(self.dimensions == vector.dimensions, "Vectors don't have the same dimensions.")

        //as @AirspeedVelocity suggested:
        return reduce(Zip2(self.coordinates, vector.coordinates), 0) { sum, pair in sum + pair.0 * pair.1 }

        //the old version:
        /*var sum: T = 0

        for dimension in 0..<self.dimensions {
            sum = sum + (self.coordinates[dimension] as T * vector.coordinates[dimension])
        }

        return sum*/
    }
}

protocol SummableMultipliable: Equatable, IntegerLiteralConvertible {
    func +(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    func *(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
}

extension Int: SummableMultipliable { }
extension Double: SummableMultipliable { }

var x = Vector<Int>(dimensions: 3)
var y = Vector<Int>(dimensions: 3)

x.coordinates[0] = 3
x.coordinates[1] = 2
x.coordinates[2] = 1

y.coordinates[0] = 3
y.coordinates[1] = 2
y.coordinates[2] = 1

println(x.dotProduct(y)) //prints 14
```

Comment: forget the dot product, I can't even get yours to not seg fault

Comment: Hmm - I currently get the problem: `'T' is not identical to 'UInt8' sum += left.coordinates[dimension] as T * right.coordinates[dimension] as T`, but I'm working on it.

Comment: I got it to stop crashing but the line: sum += left.coordinates[dimension] as T * right.coordinates[dimension] as T gives "error: 'T' is not identical to 'UInt8'"

Comment: @user678392 do you know how to fix this?

Comment: yeah, why does this work? And why do you need the extension for Vector?

Comment: The extension is not needed. You can write it, as in Update #2.

Comment: My error is now:  error: cannot invoke '*' with an argument list of type '(@lvalue T, $T14)'
            sum += vector[index]*(point[index])

Comment: by class method, I just mean a method that is a member of a class. So I want to do x.dot(y)

Comment: @445646 If you're interested in playing with another way of doing it, you could write your sum calculation as `return reduce(Zip2(self.coordinates, vector.coordinates), 0) { sum, pair in sum + pair.0 * pair.1 }`

Comment: why do we have to do self.coordinates[dimension] as T

Comment: Honestly, I don't know. If you don't include it the compiler throws an error though: `error: 'T' is not convertible to 'UInt8'`.
Maybe @AirspeedVelocity knows?

Comment: Return reduce(Zip2(self.coordinates, vector.coordinates), 0) { sum, pair in sum + pair.0 * pair.1 }  just crashes.

Comment: @marcus - pretty sure that's a Swift type inference bug causing that, it should work without it.

Comment: @user678392 `return reduce(Zip2(self.coordinates, vector.coordinates), 0) { sum, pair in sum + pair.0 * pair.1 }` doesn't crash for me. What's the error message?

Comment: It's just a long stack trace: swift                    0x000000010e1e5b68 llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(__sFILE*) + 40
1  swift                    0x000000010e1e6054 SignalHandler(int) + 452
2  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff8dabdf1a _sigtramp + 26
3  libswiftCore.dylib       0x000000011215a650 _TMPdVSs10HeapBuffer + 0
4  libswiftCore.dylib       0x000000011229a974 _TMPdVSs10HeapBuffer + 1311524
5  libswiftCore.dylib       0x0000000111f935aa _TFSs6reduceUSs12SequenceType__USs13GeneratorType___FTQ_Q0_FTQ0_QQQ_9Generator7Element_Q0__Q0_ + 490
6  libswiftCore.dylib       0x000000011229a7d2 _TFS

Comment: xcrun swift SwiftTutorial.swift

Comment: No, I mean, what IDE, etc.?
If you use Xcode, could you paste your code here (swiftstub.com), and tell me what the result is?

Comment: found the problem, but I'm not sure why it is a problem. If you type //reduce(Zip2(point, vector.point), 0) { sum, pair in sum + pair.0 * pair.1 } return reduce(Zip2(point, vector.point), 0) { sum, pair in sum + pair.0 * pair.1 }, everything works, but if you uncomment the relevant part of the code (the part that is currently commented out), then it crashes

Comment: It doesn't work. I have //reduce statement and then on the next line I have the reduce statement again. If I uncomment out the first reduce statement, it crashes. Otherwise, it works.

Comment: could you paste the whole code segment in swiftstub, save it, and paste the linke here? Because for me it works (http://swiftstub.com/867320736/)

Comment: There: http://swiftstub.com/937444572/

All that @AirspeedVeolcity's weird looking expression does is calculate the actual value of the dot product. So you have to either save the resulting value of the expression, or return it, like I did in my code (and yours now, too).
There's no need to call that expression twice :)

Comment: Yes, I know that. It was by accident that I was calling it twice. But just the fact that you are calling a function twice is making my program crahs

Comment: I don't know the reason for that though. It has to do with the magic that's going on in @AirspeedVelocity's expression.
But also a nice addition to your code might be: http://swiftstub.com/872125967/

Comment: let y = reduce(Zip2(point, vector.point), 0) { sum, pair in sum + pair.0 * pair.1} crashes my program (even if run only once), but                                    let y:T = reduce(Zip2(point, vector.point), 0) { sum, pair in sum + pair.0 * pair.1}  works fine. What the heck!?