# return Int from a generic mathematics type in swift

Tags: generics, math, swift

How to require a generic type to be usable in mathematical operations is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24046792/swift-generics-requiring-addition-and-multiplication-abilities-of-a-type/24047239#24047239)

Which led me to this protocol

```
protocol MathematicsProtocol : Equatable
{
    init(_ value: Int)
    init(_ value: Float)
    init(_ value: Double)

    func + (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    func - (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    func * (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
    func / (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Self
}
extension Int:    MathematicsProtocol {}
extension Float:  MathematicsProtocol {}
extension Double: MathematicsProtocol {}
```

used in this snippet

```
struct MyRange<DataType : MathematicsProtocol>
{
    let start : DataType
    let end   : DataType
    let step  : DataType

    subscript(index: Int) -> DataType
    {
        get {
            assert(index < self.count)
            return start + DataType(index) * step
        }
    }

    var count : Int {
        return Int((end-start)/step) //not working
//      return 4
    }
}
```

However the conversion of DataType to Int in the count function doesn't work.
Is there a way to fix this?

**Edit:**
This works, but it's an ugly hack using a string as a temporary value.

```
func convert<DataType : MathematicsProtocol>(value : DataType) -> Int
{
    let intermediate = "\(value)" as NSString
    return intermediate.integerValue
}
```

Comment: Why there is no default MathematicsProtocol in swift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define how a `MathematicsProtocol` is converted to an `Int`, e.g.
by adding a `intValue` property to the protocol:

```
protocol MathematicsProtocol {
    // ... 
    var intValue : Int { get }
}
extension Int:    MathematicsProtocol {
    var intValue : Int  { return self }
}
extension Float:  MathematicsProtocol {
    var intValue : Int { return Int(self) }
}
extension Double: MathematicsProtocol {
    var intValue : Int { return Int(self) }
}
```

Then you can use it as

```
var count : Int {
    return ((end-start)/step).intValue
}
```

Comment: Splendid. Works great.

I tried something similar by adding an init<T: MathematicsProtocol>(_ value: T), but that was a dead end. Couldn't get the types right.