# How to create a generic class in Swift that accepts Doubles and Ints

Tags: swift, generics

I have a Point class. I would like to be able to work with Ints and Doubles, like the following:

```
var p1 = Point<Int>(dimensions:3)
var p2 = Point<Double>(dimension:3)
```

I thought something like the following might work:

```
  class Point<T> {
/* n dimensional point
 multiline comments ...
*/
let point : [T]
init(dimensions: Int, repeatedValue:T=0.0){
    self.point = Array(count: dimensions, repeatedValue: repeatedValue)

}
```

}

But it doesn't.

I then tried:

```
  class Point<T:FloatLiteralConvertible> {
/* n dimensional point
 multiline comments ...
*/
let point : [T]
init(dimensions: Int, repeatedValue:T=0.0){
    self.point = Array(count: dimensions, repeatedValue: repeatedValue)

}
```

}

But then I cannot create

```
 var p2 = Point<Int>(dimension:3)
```

I can't seem to figure out a way around this. Does Swift not let you do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Int` and `Double` both conform to `IntegerLiteralConvertible`,
therefore you can define the class as

```
class Point<T:IntegerLiteralConvertible> {

    let point : [T]

    init(dimensions: Int, repeatedValue: T = 0){
        self.point = Array(count: dimensions, repeatedValue: repeatedValue)
    }
}
```

But note that if you want to do some arithmetic with the values, you will
have to define a custom protocol which defines the required operations.
See [Swift generics: requiring addition and multiplication abilities of a type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24046792/swift-generics-requiring-addition-and-multiplication-abilities-of-a-type)
for an example how this can be done.

Comment: If Double conforms to IntegerLiteralConvertible, then why can't repeatedValue take the default value of 0.0?

Comment: @user678392: Because "0.0" is a floating point literal, and not an integer literal.

Comment: So perhaps I'm confused as to what it means to be an IntegerLiteralConvertible. If x conforms IntegerLiteralConvertible, why can't you do: x = 0.0

Comment: @user678392: 0.0, 1.2, 3.1415 are *floating point* numbers. 0, 1, 3 are *integers*.

Comment: @user678392: If T conforms to IntegerLiteralConvertible, then an *integer* can be converted to T (e.g. `let x : T = 0`). That does not mean that a floating point number can be converted to T (as in `let x: T = 0.0`).

Comment: But then why does it let me create create an array of Doubles?

Comment: @user678392: Because Double conforms to IntegerLiteralConvertible. For example `let d : Double = 12` compiles, but `let i : Int = 1.2` does not.

Comment: This seems counterintuitive. So it seems that Swift says I can create an array of Doubles, but I cannot initialize an array with a hard-coded Double.

Comment: @user678392: Of course you can initialize a Double array with a "hard-coded" Double. But you cannot initialize an Int array with a double.

Comment: But point is not a (always) an Int Array. point can be a [Double].

Comment: @user678392: In the init method of the class, `T` is only known to conform to IntegerLiteralConvertible. Therefore `repeatedValue: T = 0` compiles (`0` is an integer) and `repeatedValue: T = 0.0` does not (`0.0` is not an integer). Sorry, I don't know how to explain it better.